# wxWidget C1189 #error: "wxUSE_ACTIVEX must be defined."

Tags: visual-studio, wxwidgets

I use VS2015+ wxwideget 3.10 to run a very simple example from [wxwidget examples](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/firstprograms/) 
Yesterday this example was able to run properly but today the example starts to display "Error C1189 #error: "wxUSE_ACTIVEX must be defined." when building it. I didn't change the configuration settings so this thing is quite confusing. Where could be the bugs?

the place where error occured(in chkconf.h):

```
f/* ensure that MSW-specific settings are defined */
#ifndef wxUSE_ACTIVEX
#    ifdef wxABORT_ON_CONFIG_ERROR
#        error "wxUSE_ACTIVEX must be defined."
#    else
#        define wxUSE_ACTIVEX 0
#    endif
#endif /* !defined(wxUSE_ACTIVEX) */
```

my property settings:

additional include directories: $(WXWIN)\include; $(WXWIN)\include\msvc;
additional library directories: $(WXWIN)\lib\vc_x64_lib

Comment: are you able to successfully compile and run the minimal sample provided with the library in the ${WXWIN}/samples/minimal? And any other samples from the same directory - ${WXWIN}/samples/?

Comment: tried just now, minimal samples gave the same error message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's completely impossible that something that worked yesterday stopped working today without anything else. You did change something and, of course, only you know what it was.

Second, all `wxUSE_XXX` constants are defined in `include/wx/msw/setup.h` which is copied to `lib/vc_x64_lib/mswu/wx` (or another similar directory depending on debug/release, lib/DLL build settings) during the library build and is found there by by `include/msvc/wx/setup.h`. So if it's not defined, the first thing to do is to check that this file didn't get changed somehow (maybe accidentally, although I have trouble imagining how this could happen).